# MSHTML Browser Emulation set to 0x0 crashes application in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, mshtml

If you are using mshtml as an embedded browser in Windows and want it to render in the latest installed render model (i.e. using the latest installed IE) you can use the following registry Key:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\MAIN\FeatureControl\FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION
```

And add your program name and the number "0x0". Normally you set it to a value to correspond to a specific IE version, but in my program I always want to use the latest installed version.

In Windows 10 this does not work anymore. Setting "0x0" then crashes the application if rendering a local page or gives a blank page for an Internet page. The "0x0" setting works fine with IE6-11 and Windows XP to Win 8.1.
Not setting anything gives either IE6 quirk mode or IE7 quirk mode. Setting it to "11001" in Windows 10 also works.
Is this a bug in Windows 10? (I know that the "0x0" setting is not documented...)

How do I get the latest installed Browser Emulation no matter what Windows version or IE I have installed?

P.s.
If an upgraded IE is installed after my application I still want the latest version.

Comment: Documentation for Browser Emulation: [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee330730%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396#browser_emulation)

Comment: From the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee330730.aspx): *"The FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION feature [...] supports the following values."* 0x0 is not one of those supported values. Asking the system to load an arbitrary browser control also means, that your code is running in an environment that has potentially never been tested. The registry key is provided so that you can control which specific browser you want to use. It's not there to have the system pick one at random.

Comment: I absolutely agrees there is a missing "render in latest installed browser" setting documented. It seems that 0x0 was doing just that on Windows versions before Windows 10. That's why I posted the question: How to get it done in Windows 10?